# Path.Combine returns null when Moq is used

Tags: .net, mocking, moq

I use [moq 4.17.2](https://github.com/moq/moq4/tree/803ad5c99) and [FileSystem 17.0.3](https://github.com/TestableIO/System.IO.Abstractions) for my tests.

For some reason, if the line (4) is included I always get `null` whenever I call `fileSystem.Object.Path.Combine` (e.g. in line (7)). But, when I remove line 4, then the `Path.Combine` works as expected. What can be the problem?

```
1.  var fileSystem = new Mock<FileSystem> { CallBase = true }.As<IFileSystem>();
2.  dirInfo.ExistingFiles.ForEach(existingFile =>
3.  {
4.       fileSystem.Setup(fs => fs.Path.GetDirectoryName(existingFile)).Returns("");
5.       fileSystem.Setup(fs => fs.File.Exists(existingFile)).Returns(true);
6.  });
7. var path = fileSystem.Object.Path.Combine("a", "b");
```

df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup `fs.Path.GetDirectoryName` MOQ will first [auto-mock](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties) the `Path` property recursively with a mocked `IPath` and will thus return `null` by default when you try to invoke a member that was not explicitly setup.

When you don't mock it the base class (`FileSystem`) initializes a `PathWrapper` implementation in its constructor and that is what is being invoked in your example when it behaves as you expected it.

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public FileSystem()
{
    DriveInfo = new DriveInfoFactory(this);
    DirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfoFactory(this);
    FileInfo = new FileInfoFactory(this);
    Path = new PathWrapper(this);
    File = new FileWrapper(this);
    Directory = new DirectoryWrapper(this);
    FileStream = new FileStreamFactory();
    FileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcherFactory();
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/TestableIO/System.IO.Abstractions/blob/main/src/System.IO.Abstractions/FileSystem.cs#L13)

> In this case, how can I mock `GetDirectoryName` but make the rest methods of Path work with default implementation

Do the same for those properties like you did with `FileSystem` and setup the members you want to override.

```
var fileSystem = new Mock<FileSystem> { CallBase = true }.As<IFileSystem>();

var pathWrapper = new Mock<PathWrapper>(fileSystem.Object);
pathWrapper.CallBase = true;

dirInfo.ExistingFiles.ForEach(existingFile => {
    pathWrapper.Setup(p => p.GetDirectoryName(existingFile)).Returns("");
    fileSystem.Setup(fs => fs.File.Exists(existingFile)).Returns(true);
});

fileSystem.Setup(fs => fs.Path).Returns(pathWrapper.Object);

var path = fileSystem.Object.Path.Combine("a", "b");
```